# Blurry pixels in image preview

Tags: flutter, image, dart, pixel

I'm trying to make a pixel art app using the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) but I have hit a roadblock. Individual pixels look blurry but when I export the image they look fine. Is this an image scaling issue?

I'm displaying the image with `Image.memory(encodePng(image) as Uint8List)`

Here is what the image preview looks like:
[image: Blurry pixels in image preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I resorted to drawing the image to a canvas using CustomPaint. I still don't know what caused the blurriness, but that solved my issue.